# PHPExcel passing PHP variables into spreadsheet properties

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<?php
  //Initialize variables for downloads
  $report_name = $_POST['herd-reports-download-name'];
  $filetype = $_POST['group1'];
  $farm_id = $_POST['farm_id'];
  $username = $_POST['user_name'];
  $json_array = json_decode($_POST['table_data'], true);
  $wksDescription = "Report generated for farm";

  //Branch casing depending on filetype
  switch($filetype) {
    case 'PDF':
      generate_pdf();
      break;
    case 'Excel':
      generate_excel();
      break;
  }

  //Functions for downloads here.
  function generate_pdf() {
    //echo 'pdf';
  }

  function generate_excel() {
    //echo 'excel';
    require '../includes/libraries/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  //Spreadsheet generated, one worksheet is always added to it.

    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory_serialized;
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod); //Serializes to cut memory usage slightly at a minor performance hit.

    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("myself")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("myself")
                                 ->setTitle("Report for a farm")
                                 ->setSubject("A report")
                                 ->setDescription($wksDescription)
                                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 etc")
                                 ->setCategory("Report File");

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Snoop Dawg');
    //Once it's done, begin prep to output to browser
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=vroom");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
  }
?>
```

My question is on setDescription() and setting the file name, why won't php variables work? They are currently returning nothing in those respective areas. It's probably a matter of manipulating them somehow, as setDescription() takes a string as an argument, and I'm passing a string, but it doesn't work. Nothing is being returned.

The file downloads fine, but properties that aren't strictly a string being passed aren't being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making that variable global within the function.

```
function generate_excel() {
global $wksDescription;
```

The variable doesn't exist within the scope of the function unless you pull it in from the outside.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.